# Nginx Configuration for node Js application + Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I have a nodeJS application which is configured as a docker container.For making the application up and running, i was initially using 443 as the port - which gave a message 443 is a privileged port and updated the .yml with 8443 as the port.
Previously i used to give the url like - https://abc-acde.xyz , but now have to give https://abc-acde.xyz:8443 the port also along with domain name.

To resolve this i installed **nginx** to use it as a proxy to reroute the request.

The nginx config file is configured with the key , certs along with the server details - the configuration snippet of the conf file is below :

```
 server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  abc-acde.xyz;
 
        ssl_certificate      /opt/ssl/abc-acde.xyz/abc_acde_xyz.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/ssl_signed_certs/abc-acde.xyz.key;
}
```

After this run the command - systemctl restart the nginx

Hope this configuration will help me to use the url as it was earlier - use without the port

Thanks in advance,
Rahul

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about the problem you're having?  What's not working with this setup?

Comment: Thanks David for the response. I didn't try this out. Trying to identify if this works fine or not..